# Ubuntu 14.04 nvidia-prime "is it supported? no"

Tags: nvidia, xorg, nvidia-optimus

I have an Optimus laptop, a Dell XPS 15 L502, which I've had for a few years and have tried various things on (bumblebee, nvidia-prime, linux kernel optimus support).

The graphics card is an NVIDIA GT 540M.

I upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04 a few days ago and wanted to try `nvidia-prime` again (it wasn't working so great for me on 13.10), but `nvidia-settings` only tells me that it is not supported.

Software and Updates recognises the Nvidia card and drivers.
Nvidia Settings currently gives me this:

```
** Message: PRIME: No offloading required. Abort
** Message: PRIME: is it supported? no
```

I've tried to purge and reinstall nvidia drivers a dozen times, I've tried with and without `xorg.conf` files, but still always the same thing.

I've followed all the guides I could find on Stack Overflow, Ask  Ubuntu, and various other places.

**EDIT:** I was having problem with booting into "low-graphics mode", but that was due to a bad `lightdm` configuration that broke when I upgraded. I also had some segmentation fault issues with `nvidia-settings` installing the wrong version of itself (this was fixed by reinstalling just `nvidia-settings`).

**EDIT:** Have also found this bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-prime/+bug/1283439

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have the same portable, I was using `bumblebee` before. But since 14.04 it was not working anymore and so now I switched to `nvidia-prime`. This is what I did:

**Steps**

- Install Nouveau driver through "Software & updates"
- Remove `bumblebee` or other installed `nvidia` drivers:

  ```
  sudo apt-get purge bumblebee*
  sudo apt-get purge nvidia-*
  ```
- An then reboot
- Install `nvidia 331-updates` driver through "Software & updates" (should also install `nvidia-settings` and `nvidia-prime`)
- Then reboot

Now run again `nvidia-settings`. This did it for me, more info [here](http://afterhourscoding.wordpress.com/2014/04/30/dell-l502x-optimus-support-on-ubuntu-14-04/).

Comment: I've fixed some of my other issues (thanks for putting me on the right track, but I still get the "is it supported? no" error message. Maybe it is the graphics card version? I've updated the question with the details (GT 540M).

Comment: I did just get this "working", but ended up having to uninstall nvidia again due to the massive instability issues I am having with my displays. Not sure if the problem is caused by nvidia or not, but it seems the `nvidia 331` package now supports my hardware.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem. This is just a note to whomever else might find it useful.

Things started working once I **re-enabled** optimus from BIOS.

It seems the developers didn't do enough error handling. There should really be a bug report about that.