# Ubuntu Gnome 14.04 Instal Nvidia drivers

Tags: drivers, gnome, nvidia, graphics

I have been looking all over the web, and tried every suggestion I found to get the nvidia drivers working on my computer with Ubuntu Gnome 14.04, with no luck.

Every time I install a driver or choose to use the driver from addition drivers, when I reebot, I cannot log in again. It gets stuck at the logo screen. I need to go to the ALT + CTRL + F1  to purge all nvidia traces so I can get back.

Is it possible to install the new nvidia drivers? 
I just upgraded from 13.10 to 14.04, I have an Asus N550VJ which has hybrid graphics with Intel 4000 / Nvidia 750M

What Im looking for is to try the primus functionality to disable the discreet card and enable it whenever I want to play or run heavy graphic stuff.

When I was in 13.10 I was using bumblebee, but, since, the nvidia prime is supposedly mature enough, I wanted to try it.

Is this possible for Ubuntu Gnome 14.04. I read there was a bug with gdm, but also, saw that it was already fixed.

Thank you very much for your help. Im not that well versed in linux.

Comment: you can try to boot from persistent usb and install drivers inside the live boot. this way you can experiment with all the alternatives without spoiling your installation. by the way, fresh installation is always safer than upgrade. so you may verify it as well.

Comment: read my workaround for manual installation http://askubuntu.com/questions/66328/how-do-i-install-the-latest-nvidia-drivers-from-the-run-file

Answer (score 1):

I've installed Ubuntu Gnome too and I had the same issue: logo screen freezing after installing propietary drivers. The only solution that worked to me was install nvidia 331-updates and install/switch to lightdm as default display manager.

I've followed this: [Ubuntu 14.04 nvidia-prime "is it supported? no"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/457446/ubuntu-14-04-nvidia-prime-is-it-supported-no)

And when gnome freezes after reboot:

```
sudo apt-get install lightdm
```

If you're not answered to choose between gdm and lightdm then:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

and choose `lightdm` as default display manager.

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded from 13.10 to 14.04 and used the proprietary drivers in the additional drivers area in "Software & Upgrades" You must have "Proprietary drivers for devices (restricted)" checked.

I never used bumblebee, or anything else, so you may want to try removing all of that, and then going with only the proprietary drivers and see if that makes any difference.

I am using an Asus N550J notebook btw, so it *should* work for you as well.