# NVIDIA X Server Settings don't show PRIME Profiles

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg, nvidia-optimus

I'm a new user of Ubuntu (16.04), and i've install it in my computer recently. My PC have an Nvidia GEFORCE 920MX, but i've tried everything i could and my PC still choosing the Intel Graphics as the GPU. Looking on other threads i've seen that NVIDIA X Server Setting should have an option called "PRIME Profiles" where you can choose the GPU, but this option does not appear on my NVIDIA X Server Setting:

[image]

If someone can help me it would be great. Thanks.

Comment: The driver is not installed, probably because of Secure Boot.

Comment: This helped for me https://askubuntu.com/a/538762/740447